# Doctrine user entity returns password and salt setted to NULL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Im using simple doctrine find() method to get entity of user, that should contains password and salt property. But these properties are setted to NULL immediatelly after find() call in case, that I get entity of currently logged user. Is it some security purpose of Symfony? Or it may be problem in my code?

Has anybody some option, how to solve it?

Comment: You might be pulling a proxy instance of your entity. Doctrine generates proxies when there's not enough data to build your object, so it lazy loads the object Proxies/__CG__/Your/Bundle/Entity/YourEntityName post your code, otherwise all of us will be only speculating.

Comment: It's a problem in your code.  Hard to say exactly what the problem is.  But a simple find will return the complete entity.

Comment: what is the word setted? Do you mean clearly set to null -?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your getters semantic are correctly named compared to you salt and password